# Overwriting Angular UI Bootstrap pagination template functions

Tags: angularjs, templates, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular UI Bootstrap in my application, specifically the pagination (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination).  I need/want to overwrite/extend the functions for First/Last and Previous/Next.

I've tried the following (changed the function of Last to call changePage instead of selectPage):

```
<div ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">
    <uib-pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" template-url="pagination.html" boundary-links="true" num-pages="numPages"></uib-pagination>
</div>

<script id="pagination.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious()}"><a href ng-click="selectPage(1)" title="First Page"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></span></a></li>
    <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious()}"><a href ng-click="selectPage(page - 1)" title="Previous Page"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></span></a></li>
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index" ng-class="{active: page.active}"><a href ng-click="selectPage(page.number)">{{page.text}}</a></li>
    <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()}"><a href ng-click="selectPage(page + 1)" title="Next Page"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span></a></li>
    <li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()}"><a href ng-click="changePage(totalPages)" title="Last Page"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></span> </a></li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

but that doesn't work and I'm thinking because the scope isn't right ([plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eaCOIKIwjFFlkOOHtOR4?p=preview)).

Currently I'm writing my own custom pagination, but there must be a better way?  Maybe?

Comment: Have you solved this? Thanks

Comment: I have similar problem as OP and somebody else have the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41713860/894470

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here [source uibPagination](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/pagination/pagination.js) in line 123 you see that the uibPagination directive has an isolated scope. Because of this, ng-click in your template binds to this isolated scope and not to the scope of your PaginationDemoController.

Comment: So it does have to do with the scope.  Now, to just fix it!  I will post here once I figure out the fix!