# How to assign value to angular pagination custom template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am using custom template for angular pagination:

```
            <uib-pagination
                boundary-links="(vm.pagination.boundaryLinks == false) ? false : true"
                num-pages="vm.pagination.numPages"
                total-items="vm.pagination.totalItems"
                items-per-page="vm.pagination.itemsPerPage"
                ng-model="vm.pagination.currentPage"
                max-size="(vm.pagination.pager == true) ? 0 : 10"
                template-url="pagination.html"            
                ng-change="vm.pagination.pageChanged(vm.pagination)">
            </uib-pagination>

<script id="pagination.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious()}"><a href ng-click="selectPage(1)" title="First Page"> {{'FIRST' | translate}}</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious()}"><a href ng-click="selectPage(page - 1)" title="Previous Page">{{'PREVIOUS' | translate}}</a></li>
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index" ng-class="{active: page.active}"><a href ng-click="selectPage(page.number)">{{page.text}}</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{disabled: noNext()}"><a href ng-click="selectPage(page + 1)" title="Next Page">{{'NEXT' | translate}}</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{disabled: noNext()}"><a href ng-click="selectPage(vm.pagination.numPages)" title="Last Page">{{'LAST' | translate}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</script>
<pre>Total: {{vm.pagination.numPages}}</pre>
```

It display nicely:

[image]

The problem is with the `Last` button. When I click it, it will not skip to last page. However if I assign value directly like this `ng-click="selectPage(11)` and click `Last` button, it will jump to the last page 11.

With the last code above, `vm.pagination.numPages` does contain value `11`.

[image]

Anyone can help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pagination template has isolated scope and, therefore, knows nothing about `vm`. Try `selectPage(totalPages)` instead

Comment: Thank you very much. It does worked. How do you know about `totalPages` btw? I lookup the doc here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination and there's nothing about `totalPages` keyword.

Comment: I just have some experience with using angular bootstrap pagination so I took a glance at source code